# This question about a problem from a player's perspective is not answered by the linked duplicate question from a DM's perspective

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, duplicates

[Can you make a single roll multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98500/29639) was marked as duplicate and at first "[I failed to open a lock. Now what?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49239/i-failed-to-open-a-lock-now-what)" was the only linked 'duplicate' question.

Taking a look at its answers I found that most of them, while still talking about the same issue, would not be helpful for the questioner from the new question because they were way to DM oriented ('when should you ask for a roll', 'what should be the consequences of a fail', ...)

**So I think, [Can you make a single roll multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98500/29639) is not a duplicate of [I failed to open a lock. Now what?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49239/i-failed-to-open-a-lock-now-what), because the answers are not applicable**

Now a second question, [How many times may a character attempt a skill roll for the same test?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84883/how-many-times-may-a-character-attempt-a-skill-roll-for-the-same-test), was linked as duplicate with (in my view) better fitting (but not perfect) top answer.

**I think, [Can you make a single roll multiple times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/98500/29639) could be a duplicate of [How many times may a character attempt a skill roll for the same test?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84883/how-many-times-may-a-character-attempt-a-skill-roll-for-the-same-test), because the answers are applicable.**

The problem now is, that the answers are applicable, but in my eyes missing something especially relevant for the new question, but when removing [I failed to open a lock. Now what?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49239/i-failed-to-open-a-lock-now-what) from the duplicate-question-list I wouldn't be able to answer on the new question nor on any linked duplicate, because they are themselves marked as duplicate.

My additions would also not fit in the [gm-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-techniques) question, **thus my request:** Remove [I failed to open a lock. Now what?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49239/i-failed-to-open-a-lock-now-what) from the duplicate questions and reopen [How many times may a character attempt a skill roll for the same test?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/84883/how-many-times-may-a-character-attempt-a-skill-roll-for-the-same-test) so we have one question asking for the general rules about skill-check-repeating and one question asking for [gm-techniques](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gm-techniques).

Comment: I'm not clear what you're asking for or requesting action on here. The title invites us to make generalisations about whether "I'm a player, how does foo work?" and "I'm a GM, how does foo work?" can be duplicates; we can't make a general statement about that since sometimes they can be and sometimes the GM/player different necessarily means they *aren't* duplicates. Are you concerned some of these questions shouldn't be duplicates of each other, or that they should be duplicates but linked/pointed differently? (Moderators can nowadays edit duplicate pointers.)

Comment: I find that while they are on the same topic, and possibly similar asked, the answers may vary depending on the role of the questioner.

Thus closing a question because it is a duplicate may prevent 'the other side' to get a fitting answer and it helped nobody.

Comment: Ok. So it sounds like you think one of these questions should not be a duplicate of another because the difference in role fundamentally changes the question and the answers it will receive, and you'd like to request it be reopened. Does that sound right? (You've brought up a third question in here, does that have any relationship to this request? If not, bringing it up would confuse matters.)

Comment: I brought up the 3rd question because I would accept that one as "a duplicate" because the answers are actually useful for the questioner from the new question. The top answer reflects the rules and the questioner can see how repeating ability checks work. In contrast to the "gm-techniques" question, which is useless for him, because he is not the DM. **But** even though I find the answer more fitting  I would've liked to make an addition (PCs don't know they failed, meta gaming, etc.) which is not possible because THAT question is closed, too.

Comment: Luckily I could already make my addition to the answer because I was faster than the close-vote.

**Unrelated to the example** I think we should take the usefulness of the answers in consideration before marking a question as a duplicate, not only the wording of the question.

Comment: Ok. What's going on right now with your question is this though: the body is making some observations about some questions being closed as duplicates of each other, but not saying what we should be taking from those observations, what action we should take, or even what response we might be able to provide. The title invites us to make a generalisation that cannot be made (the answer is that it varies). If you think certain questions should be reopened, or have their closure adjusted, be specific and make a specific request around what should happen. We'll be receptive to it.

Comment: Thanks for working me on this; this looks much better & I understand what you're going for. Thanks for being explicit about what you think should happen.

Comment: I hope it is ok, that I am completely ignoring the fact, that I was "fast enough" to answer with my additions on the new question. It is primarily for upcoming questions in this regard. (Or maybe the answers can be merged or something)